# Tex Live 2014 Problem

Tags: texlive

After noticing some compiling problems I ran Tex Live Utility 2014 and sure enough there was a problem.

It says "there are 520 packages available for update. Of these, the TeX Live installer packages listed here must updated first." The file is texlive.infra. After attempting an update the message comes as "the update failed." The log provides the following hints:

"tlmgr needs to be updated" tried doing that in terminal but it says I need administrator rights. Well, I am the owner so I was wondering how I can complete the step. Any other ideas?

Comment: Run in a terminal `tlmgr update --self --all` .

Comment: Depending on the system, you need to *run it as administrator* or `sudo` or whatever your OS is providing for that task.

Comment: This is what I got: Nhaps-MacBook-Pro:~ Nhaps$ tlmgr update --self --all
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/ is not writable. Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.Nhaps-MacBook-Pro:~ Nhaps$

Comment: @Nhaps `sudo tlmgr update --self` should do. The system will ask for the administrator password.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I got this result: "...done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ... done running mtxrun --generate." TexLive is working again.

Comment: The problem has already been analyzed here. I added a link

Comment: @egreg This is not a duplicate of the problem you've linked; I believe this is a completely separate issue, also discussed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230649/strange-behaviour-of-tlmgr-update

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Vote for reopening.

Comment: @egreg AFAIK I don't have enough points to vote on opening/closing/duplicates. I just wanted to give a heads-up to those who do, and leave a breadcrumb pointing to the real problem, as I'm afraid I'll be seeing more bug reports from it :(.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell I've never seen the problem, and I run TLU every day. I believe it's the old problem, though.

Comment: @egreg You could be right; there's not enough log info to know. That problem was fixed a couple months ago, though, and should not recur unless someone has a server with the one bad revision of `update-tlmgr.sh` on it. The new one we're seeing is worse.